# Jenkins pipeline library calls inside closures cause security exceptions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

We are using multibranch pipelines with organization folders (Bitbucket branch source plugin). I am DRY-ing out our pipelines using shared libraries, taking hints from [Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines) and forum posts. I am also providing scripts to other developers, trying to strike a balance between those who want everything to "just work" and those who want to customize.

I wrote a shared library including pipelines and default steps. This library is configured at the Folder level in Jenkins.

```
jenkins-lib
    vars
        pipeline_main.groovy
        pipeline_pullRequest.groovy
        ...
        default_init.groovy
```

`pipeline_main.groovy` does some initialization, with a user-provided stage if there is a Map entry with key 'init' or `default_init` if not:

```groovy
#!groovy

def call(Map config) {
    pipeline {
        agent any
        ...
        stages {
            stage ('Init') {
                steps {
                  script {
                     config['init'] ? config['init'](config) : default_init(config)
                  }
                }
            }
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

And the Jenkinsfile:

```groovy
@Library('repo/jenkins-lib') _

def customInit = { Map config ->
   echo 'Custom Init function override'
//   default_init(config)   // causes security exception if uncommented
}

if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /PR-\d+/ ) {
    pipeline_pullRequest(maven: 'maven3.3.9')
}
else if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /master|develop/ ) {
    pipeline_main(maven: 'maven3.3.9', init: customInit)
}
else {
    pipeline_feature(maven: 'maven3.3.9')
}
```

Calling the pipelines defined in the library works great, when only the defaults are used.

Now, note `customInit` method in the Jenkinsfile. For testing, I added a debug line and a call to the `default_init` step from the library. When I run a test build with this configuration (`default_init` *uncommented*), the build fails with a security exception:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object 
>   ...

If the `customInit` method is just the `echo` step the pipeline executes successfully.

I know I can whitelist the call to `invokeMethod`, but it seems I should honor the warning Jenkins gives saying to deny the request to avoid a possible security vulnerability. And, I know I can define the library at the global Jenkins level to make it trusted; however I'd prefer sticking to the per-folder method if possible.

What I'm wondering is why library methods called directly from the Jenkinsfile don't invoke security exceptions, but library methods wrapped in closures do? Or did I simply miss something else?

P.S. Jenkins 2.89.3, Bitbucket Branch Source 2.2.9, all 'Pipeline: ...' libraries at latest versions.

`default_init.groovy` content, if it matters:

```groovy
#!groovy

import java.util.Map

def call(Map config) {
    echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env | sort')
}
```

Comment: It sounds vaguely similar to [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481), but that was resolved. The Jenkins Groovy compilation behavior can be surprising.

Comment: Note that Jenkins will often throw a `RejectedAccessException` that's about `GroovyObject invokeMethod` when you typo a method name or use the wrong parameter types; places where it should throw a "no such method" error but the security system gets in the way. It's a bad interaction between sandbox security and groovy method resolution. I suspect that what was hitting you here is that your Jenkinsfile couldn't see the `default_init` method, possibly because of JENKINS-26481, and then the security system was making it so you didn't get a sensible error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at JENKINS-26481 and related JIRA issues. Indeed, I think this is a corner case the Jenkins team hasn't solved (yet?).

If I define the library at the global Jenkins level to make it trusted, then it works like I want without exceptions.